# Resizable (Zoomable) Interface in WPF

Tags: wpf

in HTML everything you do can be zoomed in or out (usually the browser supports this feature), I want to accomplish something similar in WPF. Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: Use a ScaleTransform

Answer (score 1):

As [Ed Plunkett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424129/ed-plunkett) suggested you can use a [ScaleTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example you can apply a different ScaleTransform depending on how the user moves the mouse wheel:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private double currentZoomFactor = 1;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
        FrameworkElement content = Content as FrameworkElement;

        if (content != null)
        {
            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                currentZoomFactor += .1;
                content.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(currentZoomFactor, currentZoomFactor);
            }
            else
            {
                currentZoomFactor -= .1;
                currentZoomFactor = Math.Max(.1, currentZoomFactor);
                content.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(currentZoomFactor, currentZoomFactor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Moving the wheel up makes a zoom in; viceversa wheel down makes a zoom out. I hope it can help you.